Analytical Proof for the Inequality of Minimum Values of a Transcendental Function with Varying Number of Variables
Consider the following function:
$$f_k(p_1,p_2,..,p_k) = \frac{2}{1 + d}\left((-1)^k + 2\sum_{i=1}^k (-1)^{i+1}p_i\right)\left((-1)^k + 2\sum_{i=1}^k (-1)^{i+1}p_i^{d+1}\right)$$
where $k$ is the number of variables, and the following conditions hold:

$d > 0$
$0 < p_i < 1$ for all $i = 1, 2, \ldots, k$
$p_i < p_{i+1}$ for all $i = 1, 2, \ldots, k-1$
$k \in \mathbb{N}$

I suspect that the following inequality is true:
$$\min_{p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_k} f_{k \geq 2} > \min_{p_1} f_{k=1}$$
Meaning that the minimum value of the function $f$ with more than 2 variables is always greater than the minimum value of function with one variable. As an example, consider the following:
$$f_1(p_1) = \frac{2}{1 + d}\left(-1 + 2p_1\right)\left(-1 + 2p_1^{d+1}\right)$$
$$f_2(p_1,p_2) = \frac{2}{1 + d}\left(1 + 2(p_1 - p_2)\right)\left(1 + 2(p_1^{d+1} - p_2^{d+1})\right)$$
Now I suspect that the following inequality is true:
$$\min_{p_1, p_2} f_2(p_1,p_2) > \min_{p_1} f_1(p_1)$$
I have confirmed this numerically, but I am struggling to validate it analytically. The problem arises from the fact that the derivative of this function (with respect to $p_i$) even for $k=1$ is a transcendental equation with no analytical solution. Therefore, the obvious approach of setting the derivative to zero is not possible. I am wondering if there is a way to exploit the given conditions to prove the stated inequality. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

$f$ seems to depend on $k$ and $p_1,\dots,p_k$ I find your notation very confusing. It is not at all oobvious what the minimums are over. You can't even have $p_1,\dots,p_k$ until you know $k,$ since $k$ is the number of elements.

I've changed parts of my notation and rephrased my intent, is it better now? @ThomasAndrews

I also added an example. Please let me know if it is still unclear. @ThomasAndrews

It's not clear why you call these functions "transcendental." They look like  polynomials.

I'm sorry for the confusion. The reason is that when you solve for root of derivative of $f_1$, the obtained equation is transcendental (and doesn't have a closed form solution). This is also true for higher $k$. @ThomasAndrews

If you index the $p_i$ in descending order instead of ascending, I believe you can write $f$ in the more readable form $f_k(p_1, ..., p_k) = 2/(1+d)\left[1 +2 \sum_{i=1}^k (-1)^i p_i\right]\left[1 + 2\sum_{i=1}^k (-1)^i p^{1+d}_i\right]$

@eyeballfrog thanks. That simplifies it very nicely. But I still have no clue how to handle the actual problem... do you have any suggestions?

@ThomasAndrews there is a new update.

The method I used in my answer to the $k = 2$ case can be generalized to the $k \ge 2$ case to show that at any critical point, the Hessian has a positive and a negative eigenvalue, and thus cannot be a local extremum. Indexing the $p_i$ so that $p_i > p_{i+1}$ allows for a simpler representation of the function,
$$
f_k(\mathbf{p}) = \frac{2}{1+d}\left[1 + 2\sum_{n = 1}^k(-1)^np_n\right]\left[1 + 2\sum_{n = 1}^k(-1)^np_n^{d+1}\right].
$$
The partial with respect to $p_i$ is
$$
\partial_i f_k = (-1)^i4\left(\frac{1}{1+d}\left[1 + 2\sum_{n = 1}^k(-1)^np_n^{d+1}\right] + p_i^d\left[1 + 2\sum_{n = 1}^k(-1)^np_n\right]\right).
$$
At a critical point, every one of these partials must be $0$. So, in particular, $\partial_i f + \partial_{i+1}f$ will also be zero. This allows us to cancel the first term in the expression and get
$$
\partial_i f_k  + \partial_{i+1} f_k = 4(-1)^i\left(p_i^d-p_{i+1}^d\right)\left[1 + 2\sum_{n = 1}^k(-1)^np_n\right] = 0
$$
Since by assumption $p_i > p_{i+1}$ in the domain, the only way for this to vanish is that $1 + 2\sum_{n=1}^k(-1)^n p_n = 0$. Thus, any critical point in the domain must satisfy that condition.
Taking the second derivative then gives
$$
\partial_i\partial_j f_k = (-1)^{i+j}8\left(p_j^{d}+ p_i^d + \delta_{ij}\frac{d}{2}p_i^{d-1}\left[1 + \sum_{j = 1}^k(-1)^jp_j\right]\right)
$$
The last term vanishes at any critical point in the domain, so the Hessian at a critical point will be
$$
H_{ij} = (-1)^{i+j}8(p_i^d + p_j^d).
$$
This is a rather simple rank 2 matrix whose eigenvalues can be readily found. There will only be two nonzero eigenvalues,
$$
\lambda_{\pm} = \sum_{n=1}^k p_n^d \pm 2\sqrt{k\sum_{n=1}^k p_n^{2d}}.
$$
Obviously $\lambda_+$ is positive, while $\lambda_-$ is seen to be negative from the fact that the RMS is always greater than the mean. Thus, no critical point of $f_k$ in the domain can be a local extremum and its global minimum must lie on the boundary.

As this answers part of the question and there are lots of comments, I thought it would be better to make it a post. @eyeballfrog was able to find a solution for the $k=2$ case, showing that it doesn't have a global minimum:
Proving that a function doesn't have global minimum in a specific domain
Meaning that we have to check the boundaries, and by doing so, minimum happens when:
$$p_2 \rightarrow 1$$
which converts the $f_2$ back to $f_1$. However, the method mentioned by him doesn't apply for $f$ with more than two variables, so the problem still remains unsolved.
