Proving that a function doesn't have global minimum in a specific domain
Consider the following function:
$$f(p_1,p_2) = \frac{2}{(1 + d)}(1 + 2 p_1 - 2 p_2) (1 + 2 p_1^{1 + d} - 2 p_2^{1 + d})$$
with the following domain:
$$0<p_1<p_2<1$$
$$d>0$$
My first question is, how can I show analytically that the function $f$ doesn't have a global minimum in its domain? As an example, here's the plot of the function for $d=10$:


The case for $d=0.9$:



Computing the gradient of $f$ is always a good idea. Maybe it has a nice shape

@HyperbolicPDEfriend $\frac{\partial f}{\partial p_1} = \frac{4}{1+d} ((1+2 p_1^{1+d} - 2 p_2^{1+d}) + (1+d) p_1^d (1+2 p_1 - 2 p_2))$. What is the shape of this?

The math is messy, but you can show $(\partial^2_{p_1p_1}f)(\partial^2_{p_2p_2}f )-(\partial^2_{p_1p_2}f)^2 < 0$ on the whole domain. Therefore all critical points are saddle points.

@eyeballfrog Thanks for your help. I will calculate it. Only one more thing: this question is part of another question : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4906317/analytical-proof-for-the-inequality-of-minimum-values-of-a-transcendental-functi?noredirect=1#comment10472975_4906317
where here, I've written $f_2$ only. Can your argument be extended to $f_k$?

Unfortunately no. In two dimensions, the sign of the determinant is enough to determine all eigenvalues of a matrix have the same sign. This is no longer the case in three or more dimensions.

@eyeballfrog okay the determinant is: $-16 (p_1 p_2)^{-1 +
d} (d + 4 p_1 + 2 d p_1 - 2 d p_2) (d + 2 d p_1 - 4 p_2 - 2 d p_2) -
64 (p_1^d + p_2^d)^2$

The last step is to use $(a +b)^2 = (a-b)^2 + 4ab$ to make this the sum of two terms that are always negative.

@eyeballfrog yes! thanks. 1) should I answer my question? 2) Do you have any comment on how can I approach the other problem? (the one with $f_k$)

@eyeballfrog I've computed the general derivative for $f_k$, which is: $$\frac{\partial f_k}{\partial p_j} = \frac{(-1)^k (1+(d+1) p_j^d)}{2} + \sum_{i=1}^k (-1)^{i+1} (p_i^{d+1} + (d+1) p_j^d p_i)$$

I'll post my answer for this question's case. the $k>2$ case should probably be a separate question.

I've posted the question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4906317/analytical-proof-for-the-inequality-of-minimum-values-of-a-transcendental-functi?noredirect=1#comment10472975_4906317
I would be very grateful if you could comment on it as well. Thank you very much for all of your efforts.

Since the domain is open, any global extremum must be a critical point. So if we can show that all critical points in the domain must be saddle points, then there is no global extremum. In two dimensions, a critical point is a saddle point if and only if Hessian determinant $|H| = (\partial_{11}f)(\partial_{22}f) - (\partial f_{12})^2$ is negative. So if we can determine a subset of the domain in which all critical points must lie and show the Hessian determinant is negative on that subset, we have shown all critical points must be saddles.
We can get a condition on the critical points from $\partial_1 f + \partial_2 f = 4(1 +2 p_1 - 2 p_2)(p_1^d-p_2^d)$. For this to be zero with $p_2 > p_1$, we must have $p_2 = 1/2 + p_1$.
Calculating the second derivatives is a little annoying, but they come out to nice expressions along $p_2 = 1/2 + p_1$. We have
\begin{eqnarray}
\partial_{11} f &=& 4p_1^{d-1}\left[4p_1 + d(1-2p_2 + 2p_1) \right] = 16p_1^d\\
\partial_{22} f &=& 4p_2^{d-1}\left[4p_2 - d(1-2p_2 + 2p_1)\right] = 16p_2^d\\
\partial_{12}f &=& -8(p_1^d + p_2^d).
\end{eqnarray}
From which we get that at any critical point, we have
$$
|H| = 256p_1^dp_2^d - 64(p_1^d + p_2^d)^2 = -64(p_2^d - p_1^d).
$$
This is clearly always negative, so all critical points are saddles and there are no extrema in the domain.

Thanks, this doesn't change the outcome but $p_2>p_1$

@AmirhosseinRezaei The result still holds, but this no longer justifies it as the estimates needed are tighter.

@AmirhosseinRezaei Extended the result to $p_2 > p_1$ and $d \ge 1$. Is the case $0 < d < 1$ of interest to your problem?

Thank you for your extended answer. I really appreciate it. It should also hold true for $0<d<1$, as the contour plot suggest this (I'll add the image if you ask.) @eyeballfrog

I also added the plots for the $d=0.9$ case. @eyeballfrog

@AmirhosseinRezaei OK, found proof for all $d$.

Thank you so much. Forgive me but could you please explain why the condition $\partial_1 f + \partial_2 f =0$ must also hold? @eyeballfrog

@AmirhosseinRezaei At a critical point, all partial derivatives are zero. So in particular, any linear combination of them must also be zero. Also, I believe an analogous method can be used to show the same result in higher dimensions.

thank you so much. Do you think it's possible to prove this for the general $f_{k \ge 2}$ as well?

@AmirhosseinRezaei I think that should be a separate question. I can post what I think is a proof of that if you ask it, or post it in your linked question if you think that would answer it.
